# How to solve FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly '', The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: .net, reportviewer

How to solve error:

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=15.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

I'm using .NET version 4.7 and getting this error when I try to download a PDF report using my application.

I hope this error is resolved so I can download my report PDF.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.